# Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token in semantic ui react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, button, semantic-ui-react

I recently started to study about semantic ui react. I successfully compiled the code for buttons and other components. But when I used the example of menu from https://react.semantic-ui.com/collections/menu, I got an error.

Here is the error I got after compiling:[Screenshot of compilation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ryzZJ.jpg)

And here is the code for menu :- [app.js](https://gist.github.com/ElavanResu/e5a2d44125ef2a12a277290918f6c747)

Comment: Instead of an image would be better if you post the error message as part of your question.

Answer (score 0):

I think the error is because your setup miss a babel configuration to support **class properties**.
To enable that you need to install a babel plugin:

```
npm i -D npm install --save-dev babel-plugin-transform-class-properties
```

then in your .babelrc

```
{
  "plugins": ["transform-class-properties"]
}
```

Here is the official [documentation](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-class-properties/).

---

[Here](https://github.com/arkgast/react-webpack-boilerplate) I have a configuration you can use to test the instruction I mention above. It has the `.babelrc` file and webpack configured to use it.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Do I have to create a .babelrc file? There is no such file in my project. If yes, then how to create it?

Comment: I've installed that babel plugin. I've also created that .babelrc file. Now I am getting another error. Here is the screenshot:- https://i.gyazo.com/efdd7065aa4b31b879383f60ac31aaa5.jpg

Comment: I've updated my answer providing a link to a repo I thing could be useful for you.

Comment: I did something wrong, I gave you wrong screenshot. So, when you told me to add babel configuration, I executed that command, then I added that metadata in .babelrc file. After that when I compiled I got different error.  here is my error:---- ERROR in ./App.js
Module build failed: SyntaxError: Missing class properties transform.

  3 | 
  4 | export default class MenuExampleBasic extends Component {
> 5 |   state = {}

Comment: Currently I am adding your configuration. I hope that'll work. I'll contact you asap after compiling.

Comment: Sorry for the late response, got busy with my work. The code given in the website of semantic ui didn't work. So, I changed it. Here is my code:- https://gist.github.com/ElavanResu/a3b84aaf1917594a6b7899baeac5d07c

Comment: See Topbar class. But thank you for investing your time.